# Return any response from my Web API in result object

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API. How can I return the results from all my controllers in a `Result` object, regardless of the return type of controller?

Something like this:

```
Result: {
    "isSuccess": {{True or False}},
    "value": {{Result Value Object}},
    "error": {{Error Object}},
    "totalCount": {{number of results, in case the result is list}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement what you're looking for like this:

```
public class ResultActionResult<T> : ActionResult
{
    public ResultActionResult(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        IsSuccess = true;
    }

    public ResultActionResult(Error error)
    {
        Error = error;
        IsSuccess = false;
    }

    public T Value { get; }
    public Error Error { get; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; }
    public int? TotalCount { get; set; }

    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var objectResult = new ObjectResult(this)
        {
            StatusCode = IsSuccess ? 200 : 400
        };
        await objectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

This will give you two constructors: one for successful results and the other one for error results. The four properties: Value will hold the result value object, Error will hold the error object, IsSuccess will be your boolean telling you whether the result is a success or an error, and TotalCount will holds the total number of results in case the result is a list. The class also overrides the ExecuteResultAsync method to return an ObjectResult with a status code of 200 for success and 400 for error.

To use it simply return an instance from your controller action. Hope that's what you're looking for.